# files created during container build are not preserved

Tags: dockerfile

#### The problem:

The problem is that the files and directories created during one of the `RUN` steps do not make it to the image. They're not even available from one step to the other.

#### My `Dockerfile`

I have a setup something like this...

```
COPY . /app
VOLUME /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir _TEST_ && \
    echo "hello" >> ___FILE_CREATED.txt && \
    echo $(ls) 

RUN echo $(ls)
```

I can see that in the first run `echo $(ls)` has the file and directory, and on the second run, they are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I've defined a volume for the folder

```sh
COPY . /app
# VOLUME /app <== remove this line
WORKDIR /app
```

The important bit about volumes (why the files are not persistent) is mentioned in the docs:

> Changes to a data volume will not be included when you update an image.